# find xargs mac change filename extension

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ffmpeg, xargs

I am trying to convert a directory full of mp3's (with spaces in file names) to m4a.

To convert a single file (this works):

```
ffmpeg  -i Traffic.mp3 -c:a libfaac -vn Traffic.m4a
```

The command that is failing (on OS X Mavericks):

```
find . -name \*.mp3 -print0 | xargs -0 ffmpeg -i {}  -c:a libfaac -vn {}.m4a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -type f -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:a libfaac -vn "${0%.mp3}.m4a"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `xargs`? `find -exec` is enough:

```
find . -name \*.mp3 -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:a libfaac -vn {}.m4a \;
```

The problem is that `xargs` is more similar to `find -exec … +` than `find -exec … \;`. It launches preferably just one instance of the command, replacing a single `{}` by sequence of space separated items read from input (more or less). If you want `xargs` to behave like `find -exec … \;`, you need to specify `-I{}` (`xargs -0 -I{} ffmpeg …`).

This converts `Traffic.mp3` to `Traffic.mp3.m4a`. If you want to save the conversion result to `Traffic.m4a`, you can

- rename the files after the conversion (not a very clean solution),
- execute shell in the `-exec` action and remove the `.mp3` before appending `.m4a` or
- use `xargs` after `sed`ding the `.mp3` extension away from `find` result.

I vote for the last option as it executes less processes (and shell is quite a big one, though `ffmpeg` would be difinitely so large that the difference in performance is negligible).

```
find . -name \*.mp3 | sed 's/\.mp3$//' | xargs -I{} ffmpeg -i {}.mp3 -c:a libfaac -vn {}.m4a
```

Comment: find -name \*.mp3 -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:a libfaac -vn {}.m4a \;
find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: Strange, the path is obviously required. So the dot is back again, edited. In Gnu find the path is not required and `.` is the default.

Comment: `find` + `sed` + `xargs` with `\0`-delimited file names is not portable. Only Gnu sed can handle `\x0`, AFAIK. AWK is useless in this case even in Gnu version. POSIX does not support `\0` as record delimiter at all, not even in `find` and `xargs`.